# $(0,1)$-normalization of cooperative games

Tags: discrete-mathematics, game-theory

I'm currently doing some exercises on cooperative games. To be honest I can't really find any examples of (0-1)-normalization of games. Consider the game with $N=\lbrace I,II,III \rbrace$ and characteristic function as follows:
$$v(\emptyset)=0,\ v(I)=1,\ v(II)=2,\ v(III)=3,$$
$$v(\lbrace I,II\rbrace)=5,\ v(\lbrace I, III\rbrace)=7,\ v(\lbrace II,III\rbrace)=9$$
$$v(\lbrace I,II,II\rbrace)=12$$

So the (0-1)-normalization of such game should satisfy following conditions:

1. $v(N)=1$
2. $0\leq v(S)\leq 1$ for every $S\subseteq N$
3. $v(i)=0$ for $i\in\lbrace1,2,3\rbrace$

So we know that in this normalized game
$$v'(\emptyset)=v'(I)=v'(II)=v'(III)=0,$$
$$v'(\lbrace I,II,II\rbrace)=1$$

EDIT:
Okay I think I figured this out using formula:
$$v'(S)=\frac{v(S)-\sum_{i\in S } v(i)}{v(N)-\sum_{i\in N } v(i)}.$$
By this I calculated:
$$v'(\lbrace I,II\rbrace)=1/3,\ v'(\lbrace I, III\rbrace)=1/2,\ v'(\lbrace II,III\rbrace)=2/3$$
Is that correct?

Comment: Your results are correct. No objection.

Comment: Okay so I wanted to make sure of two things. Using $v'(S)=v(S)-\sum_{i\in S} v(i)$ we get 0-normalization and $v'(S)=v(S)/v(N)$ is 1-normalization?

Comment: The former is correct, the latter holds true for $u(S):=v^{\prime}(S)/v^{\prime}(N)$.